# Trying to access hash table from finished software

Tags: c#, hash

At my company, we bought a huge software package (written in C#) which is currently being rolled out in my department.  Because of trade secret reasons my company opted to not get the service contract with the developer so now I’m in the position of learning the software/hardware on my own along with all the troubleshooting.  While doing this I made a change at some point which caused the below error which I haven’t been able to undo.  When trying to generate a report I get the following error message.

[image]

I’m trying to view the contents of the hash table so that I can delete what is reserving the key “1” or so that I can return whatever was changed so that when I generate a report it would try to enter a different key.  Do you have any advice on where the hash table is located or how I can read it?  I’ve seen other posts on how to read hash tables.  I’m just having trouble finding it.

I have access to most if not all the .h and .dll files and so I’ve been exploring those.  I took a few C++ courses a few years ago and so I have a general idea on how to read the code.

Is the hash table in the executable?  Where would it be located?  I couldn’t find it as a .txt or .mdb file.  Once I find it, how would I access it?  I could post some of the code if that would help, but I’m not sure what parts of the code would be useful to you at this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: read up on Dictionary's `Key, Value` pair.. this basically says that you cannot have 2 keys with the same value, if you have access to the `SRC` do a global search on `= new Dictionary<`

Comment: @MethodMan stacktrace shows this is `Hashtable`, not `Dictionary`. Anyway, modifying "huge software package" without any knowledge about what you are doing seems to be not very good idea.

Comment: The error is referring to `strConfig`. Have you checked your configuration files? There's probably some kind of key=value format with a duplicate key. Probably in the "reason" section, again, by the hints in the message.

Comment: You're trying to solve this at too low a level.  Forget about hashes and source code. The program is reading key/value pairs from a config somewhere that has a duplicate key value.  Fix that.  The "hashtable" is a framework class that will be in memory, not in some file.

Answer (score 0):

You are seriously out of luck, if you don't have the source code for that DTL3DTDTP thing - you'll have to reverse-engineer it to understand what happens. If you can connect to the running app from Visual Studio and intercept the exception (with "Just my code" disabled) **and** you have [Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/index) add-in installed you will be (probably) able to look at the reassembled source and call stack, maybe even variables. That HashTable is either a field of DTL3DTDTP or a local variable or something else... what and when adds the second (and the first) duplicate key to it is anyone guess... in the worst case you can reassemble the whole product and spend a month reading the code.

Of course all that will be blatantly illegal if the package is commercial - IP owners don't like reverse-engineers.

If you do have the source, just debug it.